# How to play .mp3 songs randomly by searching for them recursively in a directory and its sub directories?

Tags: linux

Once I am in the directory containing `.mp3` files, I can play songs randomly using

```
mpg123 -Z *.mp3
```

But if I want to recursively search a directory and its subfolders for `.mp3` files and play them randomly, I tried following command, but it does not work.

```
mpg123 -Z <(find /media -name *.mp3)
```

`(find /media -name *.mp3)`, when executed gives all `.mp3` files present in `/media` and its sub directories.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 10):

```
mpg123 -Z $(find -name "*.mp3")
```

The $(...) means execute the command and paste the output here.

Also, to bypass the command-line length limit laalto mentioned, try:

<s>mpg123 -Z $(find -name "*.mp3" | sort --random-sort| head -n 100)</s>

EDIT: Sorry, try:

```
find -name "*.mp3" | sort --random-sort| head -n 100|xargs -d '\n' mpg123
```

That should cope with the spaces correctly, presuming you don't have filenames with embedded newlines.

It will semi-randomly permute your list of MP3s, then pick the first 100 of the random list, then pass those to mpg123.

Comment: The output is :
devikasingh@Interest:~$ mpg123 -Z $(find /media -name "*.mp3" | sort --random-sort| head -n 10)
decoder: SSE
High Performance MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 Audio Player for Layers 1, 2 and 3
 version 0.67; written and copyright by Michael Hipp and others
 free software (LGPL/GPL) without any warranty but with best wishes
ki: No such file or directory
&: No such file or directory
fm: No such file or directory
Lifehouse: No such file or directory
Baan.mp3: No such file or directory

Playing MPEG stream 0 of 78: standard input ...

Comment: The following command worked:
find /media -name "*.mp3" | xargs -d '\n' -n10 mpg123 -Z.

By '-n' option we can provide no. of arguments for a single invocation of command

Answer (score 3):

In both [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) and [bash 4.0](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS),

```
mpg123 -Z **/*.mp3
```

(Bash users will probably need to `shopt -s globstar` first.)

Comment: I am a bash user. Kindly explain more about shopt -s globastar. What is it?

Comment: In Bash 4.0, it gives you ** which will perform a recursive search through the directory tree.  Earlier versions of Bash do not support this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Backticks.

```
mpg123 -Z `find /media -name \*.mp3`
```

Though if you have a lot of files, you may encounter command line length limitations.

Comment: The o/p gives 'find /media -name \*.mp3:No such file or directory'.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
find /media -name *.mp3 -print0 | xargs -0 mpg123 -Z
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works fine.

find /media -name "*.mp3" | xargs -d '\n' -n10 mpg123 -Z.

By '-n' option we can provide no. of arguments for a single invocation of command.

Even after I close the terminal where i wrote this command, the songs continue to play as the process mpg123 becomes an orphan and continues to run.

devikasingh@Interest:~$ ps -e | grep mpg123

```
                   7239 ?        00:00:01 mpg123
```

ps -f 7239

UID        PID  **PPID**  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD

1000      7239     **1**  0 15:21 ?        S      0:01 mpg123 -Z /media/MUSIC & PIC/audio_for_you/For You.mp3 /media/MUSIC & PIC/audio_for_you/In My Place.mp3 /

Comment: Is this a comment, an additional problem, or an answer?

Comment: Glad you got it working alright, but without the random sort, won't it always play the same groups of songs? I would expect it would pick randomly from songs 1-10, then randomly from songs 11-20, etc. and these groupings would remain constant (until you add or remove files).

Comment: I did try it, the groupings are not constant. I get to hear different songs each time I type this command. But yes.. I get to hear the songs from the same folder all the time! It seems that while searching for '.mp3', it looks into the folders in some order..Each time the same folder is getting picked. Although the songs chosen from that folder are random.

Comment: That's basically what I meant.  It looks into the folders in a deterministic order.  You might want to try the random sort.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, By using them I was able to create the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash song=$(zenity --width=360 --height=320 --title "Select Folder" --file-selection --directory $HOME) find "$song" -name "*.mp3" | sort --random-sort | head -n 100 | xargs -d '\n' mpg123
```

Comment: Please add some explainations to avoid a low quality post.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its better to use xargs, but I use a while loop in bash on Red Hat.

```
find . -iname "*.mp3" -print | sort -R --random-source=/dev/urandom | while IFS= read -r filename; do play "$filename"; done
```

The only problem with it is that it is annoying to kill.  To kill it, you must hold down Ctrl-C until the while loop is killed.

- **while**...**do**...**done** loops through each field in the **sort** output.
- **IFS** describes the field separators.
- **IFS=** makes each line a single field.
- **read** copies the current field into the *filename* variable.
- The **-r** option removes backslash processing, which doesn't seem to be necessary on Linux.
- **play** is a simple way of using **sox** for playback.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one and IMHO, much cleaner than other solutions. I don't own the credits, they goes to site owner.

```
find $HOME/mp3s -iname '*.mp3' | mpg123 -Z -@ -
```

Found on https://dannyman.toldme.com/2004/12/28/howto-mpg123-random-mp3s/

> I just changed from `name` to `iname` as sometimes files can have extension in caps...

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost all and when mpg123 is run througth a pipe it returns this error: "Can't get terminal attributes" and I cannot use terminal control keys.

The only way I found to play a list of files found with the command find and be able to use terminal control keys is this (I have directories and files with spaces):

```
find /media -type f -iname "*.mp3" > /tmp/mp3list
mpg123 -CZvv -@ /tmp/mp3list
```

It looks that mpg123 use the space as separator if you use $(find /media -type f -iname "*.mp3") and in my case doesn't work because I have spaces in all directory's names and in almost all file's names.

This is a script (playmp3.sh) to only execute find when the file doesn't exist:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! [ -f /tmp/mp3list ]; then
  find /media -type f -iname "*.mp3" > /tmp/mp3list
fi
mpg123 -CZvv -@ /tmp/mp3list
```

Answer (score -1):

I have my library in a separate partition an in my root dir i have this small script that also plays randomly previous song, i have like 40 gb of music, so they almost never repeat.

```
# !/bin/sh
cd "/media/$USER/7789f483-c7bf-46bc-9293-e8e05dd62199/musik/"
mpg123 -Z */*/*.mp3;
```